# F# equality/comparible on a generic type

Tags: f#, compare, equality

I have a record type like this:

```
type Node<'T> = { doStuff: 'T -> unit ; id: int }
```

How can I implement equality/comparible so that only the id is equated/compared?

**Note:** This needs to work between nodes of different types. So equate/compare a `Node<int>` and a `Node<string>`. It doesn't seem trivial when generics are involved.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done via a common base type:

```
type IHaveId =
    abstract Id : int
    inherit System.IComparable

type [<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>] Node<'T> =
    { DoStuff: 'T -> unit ; Id: int }

    interface IHaveId with
        member n.Id = n.Id

    override n.Equals n' =
        match n' with
        | :? IHaveId as n' -> n.Id = n'.Id
        | _ -> invalidArg "n'" "Tried to equate incompatible types."

    override n.GetHashCode () = n.Id.GetHashCode()

    interface System.IComparable with
        member n.CompareTo n' =
            match n' with
            | :? IHaveId as n' -> n.Id.CompareTo n'.Id
            | _ -> invalidArg "n'" "Tried to compare incompatible types."
```

Note that this isn't very fast. Also, be careful: With public construction access to `Node<'T>`, it would be possible to construct nodes that do something different but are treated as equals.

Using an interface for `DoStuff` would allow structural comparison. If the objects and their IDs are centrally constructed, I'd consider `[<ReferenceEquality>]` and explicitly passing a comparison function to collections that require it (such as `Set<_>` or `Map<_>`).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that writing a static member for that type will be some solution

```
static member compareNodes (n1:Node<_>) (n2:Node<_>) =
    n1.id.CompareTo(n2.id)
```